# Validation for multi-step React-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

I am trying to create a multi-step React pricing Form. I have already created the form and the pricing part.

But the user can just avoid the question and see the next part by just pressing next. So, I need some kind of validation that will prevent the user from going to the next step by completing the previous step. Can't seem to have any idea how to create one.

- **Step 1:** Radio Button Checking (Validation Not Needed)
- **Step 2:** Filling Country, City, Zip Code (Validation Needed)
- **Step 3:** Filling Email (Validation Needed)

I have created a working Code Sandbox. [Here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-calculate-in-react-form-forked-wd74i?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new `canContinueToNextStage` and set it true or false according to your logic.
Then use it to disable the next button, or in the onClick if you want to enable clicking but not to move to the next page.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what is your business logic, so this is quite hard without it. If you can elaborate I could write a sketch of POC